# Selenium xpath - locate an element using <bean:define> tag name

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have an application of web type, which contains `<bean:define>` tag. I am looking for a solution to identify this tag through `firepath` `XPath` creation.

When I dig for information related to this tag, I found it is used in `Struts` to set the scope based on the id and value parameters. Also, there are no discussions happened related to this tag.

Below mentioned web page structure :

```
<bean:define id="loggedInUserUserName" name="loggedInUser" property="firstName"> 
<iframe id="frame_admin_console" class="noautowidth" name="sample_1" rel="col1" scrolling="auto" t_src="scriptPath" style="visibility: visible; height: 861px; width: 1608px;" src="srcPath=" height="iframe_height" frameborder="0" width="100%">
```

I have tried to locate `iframe` by creating an `Xpath` of

```
.//*bean:define[@id='loggedInUserUserName']/./iframe[@id='frame_admin_console']
```

but this didn't give me a valid `xpath` in `firebug`.

Is there any way I can locate `DOM` elements of `<bean:define>` type by creating `XPATH` in selenium web driver?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can locate DOM elements of bean:define type by creating 'XPATH' in selenium web driver?

You can locate an element with this type of tag name using [`name()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name) function of the `xpath` which uses to identi as below :-

```
//*[name() = 'bean:define']
```

Or more specific

```
//*[name() = 'bean:define' and @id = 'loggedInUserUserName']
```

> I have tried to locate iframe by creating an Xpath of .//*bean:define[@id='loggedInUserUserName']/./iframe[@id='frame_admin_console'], but this didn't give me a valid xpath in firebug.

Then use as below :-

```
//*[name() = 'bean:define' and @id = 'loggedInUserUserName']//iframe[@id='frame_admin_console']
```

**Reference** : 
[name(node-set?)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35413_01/doc.722/e35419/dev_xpath_functions.htm#autoId8) Returns the complete textual node name of either a node set passed as a parameter or the current node in the current node set

This is good for information purpose. But if your goal is switching to `iframe`, you can simply switch that `iframe` using it's id attribute value (if id attribute value is unique) as below (Assuming you are using java) :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame_admin_console");
```

Comment: Thanks for the shared reference and your answers. But unfortunately, I couldn't locate element with **name()** function.
It neither located with Firepath nor with WebDriver.

Comment: It neither located with Firepath nor with WebDriver.
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[name() = 'bean:define']"}

Comment: @Ajesh make sure element which do you want to locate is outside the frame/iframe..

Comment: Yes Saurabh, the element I am looking for not belongs to any frame/iframes.

Comment: @Ajesh Did you implement some wait before finding desire element??

Answer (score 0):

If you have id's then is better to use id's, here are few examples:

```
//*[@id='loggedInUserUserName']//iframe

//iframe[@id='frame_admin_console']

//*[@id='loggedInUserUserName']//iframe[@id='frame_admin_console']
```

You can use any of these, i suggest using the second one to directly select the iframe.

Please note that if you need to interact/check any element inside the iframe you need to switch to the iframe first.

Comment: Sincere applauds for giving me nice examples, but I am looking more of a unique method to identify "bean:define" tag in XPath by including that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your XPath to locate the `bean:defined` tag

```
//*[@name="loggedInUser"]
```

But I think you need to use this way to interact with `frames`

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0); // switching in frame (Here I am using index)

// your code for interacting with element inside frames

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();  // switching back from a frame
```

Comment: I really appreciate your prompt response, but I am looking for a solution to identify "bean:define" tag. Not the alternative methods, as I am aware of to create.